# jsf dynamically generate fields of a form

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, java-ee-7

I am trying to create a dynamic form in which the user decide how many fields(most inputText or selectOneMenu) the form will have.
The use-case scenario would be:
- The user is asked how many questions his assignment will have
- The user enters the number of questions(for example 5), and click submit, the next page will display a new form with exactly 5 inputText field.

Comment: Could you provide some more details about what you have tried so far, or problems encountered?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some helpful hints.

Comment: right now I just know how to right basic jsf forms where the number of fileds is known from the get-go.                                                                 <h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="Enter your name: " />
    <h:inputText value="#{customerController.customer.firstName}" />
</h:form>.                                                                                                 I want is a way, the user can decide to have 2 or more inputtext field instead of just one